# simple typescript function with axios get call does not work

Tags: node.js, typescript, http, axios

I am learning to do http calls from node/typescript application. I have the following method, using `npm package` [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to do a http get call to a fake [api](https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2) end point.

```
    public GetTrailById(trailId: number) : string {
        console.log("Entered the method.");
        const res = axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
        .then((res: { data: any; }) => {
            console.log("inside then");
            return "this is good, got response";
        })
        .catch((err: { response: any; }) => {
            console.log("inside catch");
            return "this is not good, inner catch";
        });
        console.log("nothing worked");
        return "nothing worked";
    }
```

When I run the above code, I do see the following console outputs, but no console output from either the `then` block or the `catch` block. I dont understand where the control goes.

Output I see:

```
Entered the method.
nothing worked
```

What I expect to see:

```
Entered the method.
inside then //or inside catch
```

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning your promise to the variable `res` but not doing anything with it.

You probably want something more like:

```js
async function getTrailById(trailId: number): Promise<string> {
    console.log("Entered the method.");
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
      console.log("inside then");
      return res.data;
    } catch {
      console.log("inside catch");
      return "this is not good, inner catch";
    }
}

// ...in some other async function
const trail = await getTrailById(trailId)
```

Please note that I changed the return type to `Promise<string>` (which is what you want here since it's async) and I made the function name start with a lower-case letter (camelCase is normally used for variable and function names in JavaScript/TypeScript).

Comment: I will have to do `.then().catch()` if I want to call this async function from a non-async function right? I tried that and I need to return the data as plain string to the caller of that non-async function. How would I do that? when I add return statements inside .then() or .catch(), I get error "Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined' "