# Trying to get a simple GET response in Vue.js by pressing a button (with axios), does not work

Tags: vue.js, get, response

I have tried suggestions such as:

[Print response from http GET request using axios in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079429/print-response-from-http-get-request-using-axios-in-vue-js)

[Vue.js + Axios not assigning response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63772320/vue-js-axios-not-assigning-response)
[Get response data from axios in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017874/get-response-data-from-axios-in-vue-js)

[simple typescript function with axios get call does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61242234/simple-typescript-function-with-axios-get-call-does-not-work)

None have solved the issue.

This is the code that I have (port 2020, doesn't work with 8080 either):

```
    <template>
    <p>{{ testResponse }}</p>
      <button v-on:click="sendRequest">Get Data</button>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    const axios = require("axios");
    
    export default {
      name: 'Auth',
      created: function () {
      },
      data: function () {
        return {
          testResponse:'init',
        };
      },
      beforeMount() {},
      methods: {
        sendRequest() {
          this.getEvents("https://www.google.com");
        },
        async getEvents(url) {
          axios
              .get(url)
              .then(response => {this.testResponse = response.data})
        },
      }
    };
    </script>
    </template>
```

Pressing the button does not do anything. The GET does get sent, servers process the GET, but no data is obtained from it... What am I doing wrong ?

Edit: removed the junk.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. Nothing wrong with the code. The response needs to be JSON. It works with "https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=vue", does not work with "https://www.google.com/".